# Undefined function mysqli_connect() with Xampp

Tags: php, windows, mysqli, xampp

I will be thankful if somebody will help me to solve an issue with Xampp on Windows.

When I run this code:

```
<?php
$dbServerName = "localhost";
$dbUserName = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "gallery";

$db = mysqli_connect($dbServerName, $dbUserName, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "NOT Connected";
    exit();
}
echo "Connected";
```

I get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\muk\db.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\muk\db.php on line 7
```

I already renamed php-production to php.ini and have added extension=php_mysqli.dll (also removed ;)

Comment: Check that the `extension_dir` is correct in the ini file. Also, when you change that file, make sure to restart the PHP process.

Comment: Very strange did all steps. But no results. Still error.